# sitecore reporting DB - performance

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

we are on 8.0, Update 4.

Our Azure MS-SQL reporting database is showing massives performance spiking every day between 5am and 8am. We have 2 CD servers, and one CM server, the CM servers' app pool gets recycled daily at 5am, so i guess the spike is related to that.

This screenshot shows the query that is causing the issue, and you will notice the massive number of times that it gets run, circa 40k times over 4 hours. Does anyone know what the query is doing and how we might mitigate this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue published on the Sitecore KB https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/028657.

Your case is #2. **Disable the periodic index rebuild**

Basically, the problem occurs because of the scheduled suggested_tests_index rebuild.

Sitecore suggests removing the **/sitecore/system/Tasks/Schedules/Content Testing/Rebuild Suggested Tests Index** item from the master database. 
This item is responsible for periodic index rebuilds.

However, there are some implications. Check the article.